# How to configure the path for the UDP on the UNIX domain socket?

Tags: linux-kernel, udp, serversocket

I am new to socket programming. I'm tring to establish an UNIX domain socket with DATAGRAM. I look up the information about the configuration of **sun_path** in struct **sockaddr_un** for a while, seems like there are not enough sources to help me.

I created 3 files, unix_socket.c (provides an interface for socket connection), udp_server.c and udp_client.c, all are located in the directory **"/home/Socket**". 
When I set the **sun_path** as "home/Socket", the server side always generates an error "**Address already in use**".
I also tried using **"localSocket"** and **"echo_socket",** but the client side always generates an error "**No such file or directory**".

I have no idea what's going on. Could anybody help me fix it? Really appreciate.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The `/home/Socket` is already a folder, so it cannot be overwritten by a UNIX socket (think of it as a sort of a special file). Try another path like `/home/Socket/mysocket`.

You should also check out the [bind(2) manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man2/bind.2.html) and the example therein.

Comment: Now bind() can work. However, the new problem is that the client can send data to server and server also can receive it, but when the server sends the data back, the error "transport endpoint is not connected" comes out. Do you know what may cause this? Thank you for your reply.